# matchLabels for AuthorizationPolicy not applying in istio-system namespace

Tags: istio

I am trying to use an `AuthorizationPolicy` to control access to the inbuild dashboards in Istio (kiali, prometheus, jaeger and grafana).

When having the `Gateway`, `VirtualService` and `AuthorizationPolicy` in **istio-system**, I am not able to use `matchLabels` to apply `AuthorizationPolicy` to the worksloads I want. Regardless of what label I use it seems to ignore it. But if I move the `AuthoriztionPolicy` and `Deployment` to a separate namespace all is fine.

Slightly simplified example (which does not work) where workload is a simple nginx container and `AuthorizationPolicy` is DENY just to see that is has an effect.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-addons-ingress-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http-web
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
    hosts:
      - 'kiali.{{ required "A valid .Values.domainName entry required!" .Values.domainName }}'
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https-web
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: {{ .Chart.Name }}-addons-tls
    hosts:
      - 'kiali.{{ required "A valid .Values.domainName entry required!" .Values.domainName }}'
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kiali-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "kiali.{{ required "A valid .Values.domainName entry required!" .Values.domainName }}"
  gateways:
  - {{ .Chart.Name }}-addons-ingress-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: kialitest.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ext-authz
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  action: DENY
  rules: 
  - {}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kialitest
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: kialitest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: kialitest
      labels:
        app: kialitest
        version: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kialitest
        image: nginxdemos/hello
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kialitest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kialitest
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: kialitest
```

If I instead create a new namespace and move `AuthorizationPolicy`, `Deployment` and `Service` there and update the `VirtualService` destination, everything works are expected. Does the **istio-system** namespace behave differently?

Kubernetes 1.20.7 and Istio 1.11.3

Comment: I don't think that the `istio-system` namespace behaves differently. It is possible though that there are other objects present which influence its behaviour.

Comment: After more investigation today I found I had overlooked that `istio-system` does not have istio-injection label set. So neither kiali nor my test did get envoy injected. Is there any reason I should not enable istio-injection on `istio-system`? I could always create a separate namespace for the inbuild dashboards, but then I would have to customize the default yaml files provided by Istio and that introduce more work for every upgrade.

Comment: I also realized the inbuilt dashboards have `sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"` which makes me feel like I am doing something wrong.